# What is the purpose of the "second click" selection mode in the interface builder?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

When I click a UI element while designing a XIB, the UI element is selected like this:
[image: Selected button]

If I click the same element again it is selected like this:

[image: "second-click"-selected button]

What is the purpose of this special selection mode?

Comment: Oh God. This question is finally **not** abusing the `xcode` tag. +1 for that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, this is just a mechanism for traversing the view hierarchy (and lock focus on nested subviews). While it seems that there's no difference between two modes in your example (except of course the lack of the resize handles in the 'focused' one) consider a more complicated object such as a tableview on OSX (notice also how the light blue color indicates the view being edited while the focus ring indicates its superview's frame - also note that this drill-down is based on the location of the mouse pointer. In this example in order to travel all the way down to the cell we have to click inside the bounds of the innermost element we're aiming at):

**1st Click** - Selects the outer element / container (ScrollView)
[image]

**2nd Click** - Selects the TableView
[image]

**3rd Click** - Selects the TableColumn
[image]

**4th Click** - Selects the TableCell
[image]

Comment: Interesting. If I build a similar view hierarchy (scrollView -> tableView -> cell -> label) in a iOS storyboard the first click selects the innermost label directly.

Comment: @MatthiasBauch Correct. The difference is that the elements on the OSX tableview are pre-embedded. Also if you take a look on a `UIToolbar` with a `UIBarButtonItem` inside it, you should see that it works (since a `UIBarButtonItem` cannot exist outside a `UIToolbar`). Apple should have documented this feature imo.

Comment: That makes sense. Totally forgot about that behavior for UIToolbar (and UITabBar too). Thank you very much.